# Convert code to Lambda function

Tags: lambda, java-8

Hi I have the following code which gets cookie form a `HttpURLConnection` object.

```
           for (int i=1; (headerName = connection.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++){
                if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")){
                    String cookie = connection.getHeaderField(i);
                    cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
                    String cookieName = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("="));
                    String cookieNameFromConfig = TalismaConnector.config.getValue("api.authentication.cookiename");
                    if (cookieName.equals(cookieNameFromConfig)){
                        //the right cookie to get the content from.
                        jsessionID = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.length());
                        OptJsessionID = Optional.ofNullable(jsessionID);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I like to write this as a robust lambda function using java 8.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is the stop at `null` condition as `Stream`s do not support stopping on an arbitrary `Predicate`. The only way to handle this is to let both, matching items and `null`, pass down the `Stream` and use `findFirst` to find either, a match or the first `null`.

Since we don’t want to deal with that `null` in all intermediate steps, we apply these steps to an `Optional` encapsulating the matching item rather than the `Stream` itself as the `Optional` will do nothing if empty.

```
String cookieNameFromConfig = TalismaConnector.config.getValue(
                                                     "api.authentication.cookiename");
IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i+1)
.filter(i -> { String k=connection.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
               return k==null || k.equals("Set-Cookie"); })
.mapToObj(i -> Optional.ofNullable(connection.getHeaderField(i))
  .map(cookie   ->cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";")))
  .filter(cookie->cookie.regionMatches(0,cookieNameFromConfig,0,cookie.indexOf("="))))
.findFirst().get().ifPresent(cookie -> {
        //the right cookie to get the content from.
        jsessionID = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.length());
        OptJsessionID = Optional.of(jsessionID);
});
```

Comment: @Vinay Joseph: that’s what I explained in the second sentence, the predicate accepts both, a `null` header field or the `"Set-Cookie"` so that the `findFirst` will find either a match or `null`, whichever comes first. Since the stream will encounter `null` values only when it has processed all existing header fields, encountering `null` implies that there is no match. If `null` is encountered, i.e. no match found, `findFirst().get()` will evaluate to an empty `Optional` and it’s `ifPresent` method will do nothing.

Comment: I just wasn't familiar with the syntax of return True || False

Comment: @Vinay Joseph: oh well, that’s something out of the scope of a lambda expression question. But never mind; the important thing about that `||` “logical or” is that it doesn’t evaluate the second expression if the first evaluated to `true`, so if `k` is `null`, Java will not try to invoke `equals` on it.

Comment: I really appreciate your time. Thank you.